# Why does Postman request to Adonisjs API work but get a CORS error when calling from fetch() in my Vue 3 app?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, adonis.js

I can not figure out why I'm getting a CORS error when trying to login from my Vue 3 / Ionic app in the browser. My login request works from Postman without issue.

Here is what my fetch call looks like.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3333/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(creds)
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Here is what the headers in my request looks like

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3333/api/login
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36
```

The response in my Network tabs response says "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"

The config/cors.js file has the stock config so it should just work?

The method I'm calling in my Auth controller looks like this.

```
public async login({request, response, auth,}: HttpContextContract){
    const {email, password} = request.only(['email', 'password'])

    try {
      const token = await auth.attempt(email, password)
      return token
    } catch (error) {
      return response.json({error: 'You failed to login. Please check your email or password and try again'})
    }

  }
```

Comment: When using CORS you have to define the allowed origins of requests going to the client.

Comment: I set the 'origin' value to true. The documentation says this will allow any origin. https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/security/cors

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to have more details about the API you're calling when attempting to log in from your frontend application, i.e. the CORS configuration you've applied in your API source code.

Comment: Rout looks like this. Route.post('api/login', 'AuthController.login').as('auth.login') and I added the method that is getting called to my question above. 

Like I said. It works when calling from Postman but calling from my ionic app on localhost:8100 to the API on localhost:3333 keeps giving me a CORS error. I even copied the fetch method that Postman generates for me and put it in my Vue/Ionic app and I get a CORS error.

Comment: Because Postman is not a browser and therefore doesn't care about CORS, but any decent browser in its standard configuration does ... Also "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier" does not seem to be related to CORS at all ...

Comment: Furthermore the *request* headers are (more or less) irrelevant for this problem. You have to look at the **response** headers. They have to contain the correct `Access-Control-...` headers. If they don't contain these headers, your server configuration is wrong

Comment: @derpirscher I understand that. looking at the adonisjs docs at the cors config, I'm not sure where to begin to troubleshoot this.

Comment: first of all, have a look at the developer tools in the browser and check the console (because it will point out which *exact* error happened) and the headers of the response, if it does indeed contain the necessary headers. If not, show some of your backend configuration, because currently, all that you show is for the frontend, which is irrelevent for solving this issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by going into the config/cors.ts file in my AdonisJS project and setting `enabled: true`  https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/request#cors

Why this is not set to true for an API framework is beyond me, but this solved the problem.

Comment: Because "API" does not automatically mean, there will be a web-frontend which needs CORS. And automatically enabling CORS without any restrictions may also not be the best idea. If someone needs CORS, he should think about *what* part of it is really needed and then enable just that.